# Get information about post on Facebook with GraphQL API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, graphql

The example I have a post on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/dji.europe/posts/2044303259123118
How to get information from the post such as like count, caption, comments count and text of comments and other information, using Facebook GraphQL.
Can I get the same information, from not business accounts?

Comment: I have the access token.

Comment: You’ll need to translate the page name into the numeric ID first (API request using the page name), and then combine page id and post id with an underscore in between them. // If by “non business accounts” you mean user profiles - then you would need to get permission to read their posts from the individual user first.